# Service account for authenticating with the Clockify API?

Tags: clockify

I need to authenticate with the Clockify API but I do not want to use the API key of any of my existing users for this. Also, since I am going to use the API only for data extraction it does not seem right to create a user, since essentially it will not be used by a human but by a data extraction service. Does Clockify have service accounts or something similar?

I have already looked through the Clockify docs and searched Google for possible solutions, but the only solution I can seem to find is to use a normal user account.